# How do you transition date from one column to the next in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a program that displays the amount of seconds in a day (86400) which means there will be 86400 rows of data displayed from 00:00:01 to 59:59:59 in that format. However I get a Run-time error: Overflow. Therefore, I am assuming I need to use more than one column to collect this data - if so how do I do that?

```
Private Sub mythirdlesson()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim h As Long
Dim cellrow As Integer

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Library")
cellrow = 1

For h = 0 To 59
    For m = 0 To 59
        For s = 0 To 59
        wks.Cells(cellrow, 1) = h & ":" & m & ":" & s
        cellrow = cellrow + 1
        Next
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with the Excel rows but rather with the `cellrow` data type. I changed it to long and it worked without issue. Also note that your script has a design error calculating 60 hours in a day rather than 24. Please consider the corrected script:

```
Private Sub mythirdlesson()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim h As Long
    Dim cellrow As Long

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Library")
    cellrow = 1

    For h = 0 To 23
        For m = 0 To 59
            For s = 0 To 59
            wks.Cells(cellrow, 1) = h & ":" & m & ":" & s
            cellrow = cellrow + 1
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: This should fix your issue though it doesn't respond to your specific question. If you want to break it into 2 lines you can have an `IF cellrow>43200 THEN` statement where if `cellrow` or some other variable goes beyond a certain value in your nested loop then you would execute `wks.Cells(cellrow - 43200, 2) = ...` writing on the second column and adjusting your row. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Working with arrays is always faster. The code below populates 86400 rows in 0.4 sec on my PC, against 5.3 sec for `wks.Cells(cellrow, 1) = h & ":" & m & ":" & s` method:

```
Sub TestFill86400()
    Dim filler(1 To 86400, 1 To 1) As Date
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 86400
        filler(i, 1) = (i - 1) / 86400
    Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Library")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(86400, 1))
            .Value = filler
            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert to a .xlsx, .xlsm and .xlsb workbook?  They have a limit of 1048576 rows per sheet.

Also, you will have to change the data type of `CellRow` to `LONG`.

If you still need to break it into more than one column you can use modular opreations... like this:

```
Private Sub mythirdlesson()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim h As Long
Dim cellrow As Long

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
cellrow = 0

For h = 0 To 24
    For m = 0 To 59
        For s = 0 To 59
            wks.Cells(cellrow Mod 65536 + 1, cellrow \ 65536 + 1) = h & ":" & m & ":" & s
            cellrow = cellrow + 1
        Next
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize you are doing this exercise for practice and to learn VBA. Here's a good lesson regarding speed. Look how long it takes to write out your 86400 time values, the way you are doing it in this exercise.

Here's how I would do it. It takes about tenth of a second to complete:

```
Private Sub FastTimes()
    [d:d].NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    [d1:d86400] = [row(1:86400)/86400]
End Sub
```